# R repository not signed

Tags: updates, repository, r

When i `sudo apt update`, I get the following message:

```
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ Release' is no longer signed.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Initially, I had added the repository based on https://cran.r-project.org/ to /etc/apt/sources.list.

Please help, I do not understand what "repository is no longer signed" means. I removed and added the repository again, but that did not improve things.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue on three different machines today.

The main problem is that *Release.gpg* key file is really missed on server  (repository) side.
We can't do anything with it by ourselves.

I have written an e-mail to the key owner (Michael Rutter) to inform him about the problem and got the following reply:

> Had a server crash.  Fixed and things should be fine after next CRAN sync.

**Update 2019-06-05 01:04**: the Release.gpg file is in place.